# Вставить данные json из файла в html

Tags: jquery, json

Здравствуйте!
Помогите пожалуйста разобраться в вопросе:
Беру json данные из внешнего файла и пытаюсь вставить в предназначенные для них элементы.
Но у меня получается, что в div.name записываются все полученные name, div.age записываются все полученные age и т.д.
Например: Имя: ИванЕкатеринаФедорСтаниславЕвгенийЕлена
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Как сделать чтоб каждого прохода $.each, создавалась своя таблица со значениями.
Содержание json:

```
[
  {
    "name": "Иван",
    "age": "32",
    "email": "ivan@ivanov.ru",
    "phone": "+7(954)148-45-73",
    "address": "Торфяная ул. 7/4"
  },
  {
    "name": "Екатерина",
    "age": "24",
    "email": "katja@yandex.ru",
    "phone": "+7(956)172-12-23",
    "address": "Никитинская ул. 12б"
  },
  {
    "name": "Федор",
    "age": "45",
    "email": "fedor@sidirov.ru",
    "phone": "+7(911)760-45-35",
    "address": "Ленинский пр-т. 74/3"
  },
  {
    "name": "Станислав",
    "age": "19",
    "email": "stas@fedorov.ru",
    "phone": "+7(954)343-55-55",
    "address": "Московский пр-т. 14/4"
  },
  {
    "name": "Евгений",
    "age": "28",
    "email": "evgeny@gmail.com",
    "phone": "+7(918)577-98-89",
    "address": "Советская ул. 60"
  },
  {
    "name": "Елена",
    "age": "22",
    "email": "elena@mail.ru",
    "phone": "+7(931)466-77-19",
    "address": "Есенина ул. 4"
  }
]
```

Спасибо!

```js
$.getJSON('test.json', function(data){
  console.log(data);

  $.each(data, function(key, val){
    var name = val.name;
    var age = val.age;
    var email = val.email;
    var phone = val.phone;
    var address = val.address;

    $('.table-template').clone().appendTo('body');
    $('.table-template').find($('.name')).append('<span>' + name + '</span>');
    $('.table-template').find($('.age')).append('<span>' + age + '</span>');
    $('.table-template').find($('.email')).append('<span>' + email + '</span>');
    $('.table-template').find($('.phone')).append('<span>' + phone + '</span>');
    $('.table-template').find($('.address')).append('<span>' + address + '</span>');
  });

});
```

```css
.table div {
      display: inline-block;
      width: 200px;
      border: 1px solid black;
      margin: 10px;
      padding: 5px;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="table-template table">
          <div class="name">
            <span>Имя:</span>
          </div>
          <div class="age">
            <span>Возраст:</span>
          </div>
          <div class="email">
            <span>E-mail:</span>
          </div>
          <div class="phone">
            <span>Телефон:</span>
          </div>
          <div class="address">
            <span>Адрес:</span>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: какой результат должен быть

Comment: при получении данных, в новую таблицу записывались данные из json.

Comment: Да, понять бы вопрос ;)) или в чем разобраться ?!

Comment: Понял, где недопонимание) поправил пост.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот такой вариант:

```js
// Propagate template.
(function(selector) {
  var template = document.querySelector(selector);
  var arrayDataProvider = getJsonAsArray();
  arrayDataProvider.forEach(function(element) {
    var templateClone = template.content.cloneNode(true);
    templateClone.querySelector('.name > span').textContent +=
      ' ' + element.name;
    templateClone.querySelector('.age > span').textContent +=
      ' ' + element.age;
    templateClone.querySelector('.email > span').textContent +=
      ' ' + element.email;
    templateClone.querySelector('.phone > span').textContent +=
      ' ' + element.phone;
    templateClone.querySelector('.address > span').textContent +=
      ' ' + element.address;
    document.body.appendChild(templateClone);
  });
})('#table-template');

function getJsonAsArray() {
  return JSON.parse(`[
    {
      "name": "Иван",
      "age": "32",
      "email": "ivan@ivanov.ru",
      "phone": "+7(954)148-45-73",
      "address": "Торфяная ул. 7/4"
    },
    {
      "name": "Екатерина",
      "age": "24",
      "email": "katja@yandex.ru",
      "phone": "+7(956)172-12-23",
      "address": "Никитинская ул. 12б"
    },
    {
      "name": "Федор",
      "age": "45",
      "email": "fedor@sidirov.ru",
      "phone": "+7(911)760-45-35",
      "address": "Ленинский пр-т. 74/3"
    },
    {
      "name": "Станислав",
      "age": "19",
      "email": "stas@fedorov.ru",
      "phone": "+7(954)343-55-55",
      "address": "Московский пр-т. 14/4"
    },
    {
      "name": "Евгений",
      "age": "28",
      "email": "evgeny@gmail.com",
      "phone": "+7(918)577-98-89",
      "address": "Советская ул. 60"
    },
    {
      "name": "Елена",
      "age": "22",
      "email": "elena@mail.ru",
      "phone": "+7(931)466-77-19",
      "address": "Есенина ул. 4"
    }
  ]`);
}
```

```html
<template id="table-template">
  <hr>
  <div class="table-template table">
    <div class="name">
      <span>Имя:</span>
    </div>
    <div class="age">
      <span>Возраст:</span>
    </div>
    <div class="email">
      <span>E-mail:</span>
    </div>
    <div class="phone">
      <span>Телефон:</span>
    </div>
    <div class="address">
      <span>Адрес:</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <hr>
</template>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/5p4hn4py/

Comment: Спасибо за ответ!  Но для меня это немного сложно буду разбираться. Ответ от L. Vadim для меня понятнее. Подскажите,а что не так в моём варианте, как я понимаю, цикл $.each должен по каждому проходу создать табличку клон и внести данные.

Comment: Вот ваш правильный вариант: https://jsfiddle.net/nqckmbd4/.

Answer (score 1):

```
for(i=0; i < data.length; i++)
{
          document.getElementsByClassName('table-template')[0].innerHTML += '<div class="table-template table">'+
          '<div class="name"> <span>Имя: '+data[i]["name"]+'</span></div>' +
          '<div class="age"><span>Возраст: '+data[i]["age"]+'</span></div>' +
          '<div class="email"><span>E-mail: '+data[i]["email"]+'</span></div>' +
          '<div class="phone"><span>Телефон: '+data[i]["phone"]+'</span></div>' +
          '<div class="address"><span>Адрес: '+data[i]["address"]+'</span></div>' +
          '</div>';
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Но подскажите, а что не так в моём примере, ведь там так же используется цикл?

Comment: пожалуйста, ваш цикл бежал несколько раз и постоянно вписывал в одну ячейку все параметры.